# Publish Asp.net Core 3.1 Web Api on Azure Linux Ubuntu 18.04 VM

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-core, ubuntu, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to publish the application on Azure Linux Ubuntu 18.04 VM. i configure step mention below step on VM but i am facing  404 url Not Found issue.
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at myipaddress Port 80 error

I have only simple WeatheForeCast web api controller which is default in asp.net core web api 3.1

I have followed below commands by connecting VM

```
sudo -i

wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1

sudo apt-get install aspnetcore-runtime-3.1

sudo apt-get install dotnet-runtime-3.1

sudo apt-get install apache2

systemctl restart apache2

a2enmod proxy proxy_http proxy_html proxy_wstunnel

sudo a2enmod rewrite 


vi /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/webapplication4.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>  
   ProxyPreserveHost On  
   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/  
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/webapplication4-error.log  
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/webapplication4-access.log common  
</VirtualHost>
```

cat /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/webapplication4.conf

```
vi /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/webapplication4.conf

cat /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/webapplication4.conf

systemctl restart apache2

sudo chmod 777 /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/webapplication4.conf

cd /var/


mkdir WebApi

cd WebApi
```

i have published webapi with folder option

With  netcoreapp3.0 as Target Framework and Framework-Dependent as Deployment Mode

Selected linux-x64 as Target Runtime, as we want to host our application in Linux environment

and tranfer file using winscp software and Copied file using below command

```
cp -R * /var/WebApi/

vi /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-webapplication4.service

[Unit]  
Description=Aspnet Core Web Api running on Ubuntu 18.04  
[Service]  
WorkingDirectory=/var/WebApi  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/WebApi/webapplication4.dll  
Restart=always  
RestartSec=10  
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-demo  
User=www-data  
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production  
[Install]  
WantedBy=multi-user.target



sudo systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-webapplication4.service

sudo systemctl start kestrel-webapplication4.service
```

http://MyIpaddress/WeatherForeCast it shows 404 url not found. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at MyIpaddress Port 80

Comment: Could you access the lcoalhost:5000/WeatherForeCast in the Linux server?

Comment: I used curl 'http://localhost:5000/WeatherForeCast' command and  its working

Comment: I suggest you could try to follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-apache) to add the conf file to the right folder and try again.

Comment: I tried this article. httpd directory not available in ubuntu 18.04. I am using apache2 server

Comment: I have tried your command and it works well on my side. I suggest you could check the `/etc/apache2/httpd. conf` file to make sure you have added include the conf-enabled folder.

Comment: I have my file webapplication4.conf on this path /etc/apache2/conf-enabled. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you could try to directly add the rule into the httpd.conf and test again. I guess the webapplication4.conf  my not executed.

Comment: I added the file but it still not working. Please  suggest any solution

Comment: Since we don't know how your Azure VM setting, I suggest you could consider creating a support ticket to Azure support to let them remote your VM. About how to ask Microsoft Azure support, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/).